# How to NOT connect as NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM in SQL Server 2012 using ServerConnection?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on .NET application which connects to SQL Server database using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server` classes.

This application is invoked by an installer which runs as NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM. So this application is also run as the same user. This worked fine for SQL Server 2008 since, that user is a `sysadmin` in 2008, but in 2012 its not.

```
ServerConnection serverConn = new ServerConnection();
serverConn.LoginSecure = true;
```

The above code indicates the *invoker of the application* is used to connect to SQL Server.

I cant enable (rather dont want to) enable mixed mode and provide username/password.

Is there any way to not use NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM to connect, but rather use the current logged in user? The installer sets the currently logged in user as a `sysadmin`.

Comment: is the application *invoked* by an installer? Or is it installed by the installer and launched as a service? It would be highly unusual for an installer to invoke an application as system.

Comment: Yes. It is *invoked* by the installer. Its not a service, but an executable. The installer runs as system.

Comment: There is no pixie dust here. A process authenticates as the credential running it. Installer runs as System, then your app runs as System, and trying to change *that* is definitely barking up the wrong tree (including using runas.exe). The installer should not run as System (and that applies to remote, OEM and startup installers). Have the installer run as the required user (preferably as the actual admin doing the install).